# GroovyObject medhods' default implementation

Tags: java, groovy, bytecode

I'm moving to Groovy from Java.

I have a non-abstract Groovy class, when I compile it and view the bytecode I see that my class implements GroovyObject interface, but there is no any implementation of GroovyObject's methods in the bytecode of my class. 
I thought that the bytecode generated by Groovy compiler should be a valid bytecode for Java executable(of course we have to include groovy-all-x.x.x.jar into the classpath), but seems that it's not the case.

I believe some magic happens using groovy-all-x.x.x.jar during runtime but   I'm not sure what exactly is going on there.

Any idea ?

Comment: http://www.groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html

Comment: when groovy class is compiled to bytecode i have to be able to run that class with java executable (just adding groovy jar to the classpath), right ? But for java this class is invalid as it doesn't implement its contract. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Yes, to call Groovy code you need the Groovy jar, which Groovy's run-time system; It's what handles method dispatching for Groovy code. The book "Groovy in Action" thoroughly explains how Java and Groovy code interact.